Why is the first command line arg lost in .NET Core app when it is run by C++ app - CreateProcess()
C++ app runs .NET 8 TestApp.exe
CreateProcessW(L"D:\\TestApp.exe", L"-x \"MY_PARAM\"", NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)

Then the command line is checked in this TestApp
.NET 8
[D:\TestApp.dll,MY_PARAM] - Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
"D:\TestApp.dll" MY_PARAM - Environment.CommandLine

kernel32.dll
-x "MY_PARAM" - GetCommandLine()

If TestApp is .NET Framework 4.7.2
[-x,MY_PARAM] - Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
-x "MY_PARAM" - Environment.CommandLine

Please, do you know why the first command line argument (-x) is lost in .NET Core app?
It looks OK when TestApp is run from .NET Framework or .NET Core app.
Or when a space is added before the first arg " -x "MY_PARAM"".
Is it a bug in .NET Core?
Thank you.

The second argument to CreateProcessW is not the command line arguments, it's the entire command line.  The first thing on that command line is the program being run.  Change it to L"D:\\TestApp.exe -x \"MY_PARAM\"" to see if that takes care of the problem.

If the command line contains a space (or the program path), it works (the argument is passed to .NET Core app). Do you think that CreateProcessW() is not used correctly? Or is it required by .NET Core? (.NET Framework works as I expected.)

According to the Environment.GetCommandLineArgs documentation:

An array of strings where each element contains a command-line argument. The first element is the executable file name, and the following zero or more elements contain the remaining command-line arguments.

So, the use of the word remaining implies the 1st command line argument is assumed to be the module name.
According to the CreateProcessW documentation:

If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by lpCommandLine specifies the command line. The new process can use GetCommandLine to retrieve the entire command line. Console processes written in C can use the argc and argv arguments to parse the command line. Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.

So, you need to repeat the module name in your command line, eg:
WCHAR szCmdLine[] = L"D:\\TestApp.exe -x \"MY_PARAM\"";
CreateProcessW(L"D:\\TestApp.exe", szCmdLine, ...);

Otherwise, simply don't use both parameters, use only the lpCommandLine parameter and let CreateProcessW infer the module name for you:

If lpApplicationName is NULL, the first white space–delimited token of the command line specifies the module name. If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin (see the explanation for the lpApplicationName parameter). ...

WCHAR szCmdLine[] = L"D:\\TestApp.exe -x \"MY_PARAM\"";
CreateProcessW(NULL, szCmdLine, ...);


Thank you RemyLebeau and @Eljay. I first read documentations before asking.
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs docs are the same for .NET 8 and .NET Framework. But the behavior is different. And I couldn't find any note about it.
